# Android using a boolean flag to define user input

Tags: java, android, boolean, user-input

I apologise if the syntax is off here, especially regarding the Boolean:

```
public class WeightConverter extends Activity implements OnClickListener, OnCheckedChangeListener {
    Button convertWeight;
    TextView conversionResults;
    EditText enterWeight;
    RadioGroup weightPicker;
    RadioButton radKG, radLB;
    double weightValue, convertedWeight;
    String weightString;
    String measurement;
    Boolean weightSwitch;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.weightconverter);
        initializeVariables();
        weightSwitch = false;
        radKG.setChecked(true);
    }

    private void initializeVariables() {
        convertWeight = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnConvertWeight);
        conversionResults =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvWeightConversion);
        enterWeight =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.etWeightToConvert);
        weightPicker = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.rgWeightType);
        radKG = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radKG);
        radLB = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radLB);
        convertWeight.setOnClickListener(this);
        weightPicker.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);


    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        switch (v.getId()) {

        case R.id.btnConvertWeight:

            if (weightSwitch = true){
                convertedWeight = weightValue /2.2;
                measurement = "Kilograms";
            }else{
                convertedWeight = weightValue *2.2;
                measurement = "Pounds";
            }


            conversionResults.setText(weightValue + " = " + String.valueOf(convertedWeight) + " " + measurement);
            break;
        }

    }

    @Override

    public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
        weightValue = Double.parseDouble(enterWeight.getText().toString());
        switch (checkedId) {

        case R.id.radKG:

            weightSwitch = true;

            break;
        case R.id.radLB:

            weightSwitch = false;

            break;

        }
    }



}
```

Depending on whether the user selects either of the Boolean types a different calculation should be performed, however only the conversion to pounds is working..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are attempting to compare `boolean` values with the `=` operator in this line:

```
if (weightSwitch = true){
```

But `=` is the assignment operator, so `weightSwitch` is always `true`.

Use `==` to compare `boolean` values, or better:

```
if (weightSwitch)
```

because it's already a `boolean` value.

Comment: awesome!! slight niggle though, if i don't _exclusively_ specify a radio button then the calculation returns 0 ie. if i just enter a value and press convert it just returns 0, only when i press either radiobutton does the calculation occur, i feel it has something to do with "radKG.setChecked(true);" ?

Comment: I'm not currently familiar with Android; I just saw your error which happened to be related only to pure Java.